# Rails 3 beta 3 -- is it time to start using this for new projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it time to start new projects in Rails 3? I'm nervous about using beta versions but at the same time I really like what they are doing and don't want to deal with legacy 2.3.5 issues with these apps.

Is it better to wait these things out, or buckle-up, deal with early adopter issues and get a head start on the future. Thanks for any light you can shed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say no, rails v3.beta3 still has some serious issues that cause it to crash (unexpectedly). [As noted from the Riding Rails blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/4/1/rails-3-0-second-beta-release):

> Note that Ruby 1.8.7 p248 and p249 has marshaling bugs that crash both Rails 2.3.x and Rails 3.0.0. Ruby 1.9.1 outright segfaults on Rails 3.0.0, so if you want to use Rails 3 with 1.9.x, jump on 1.9.2 trunk for smooth sailing.

Also of note:

> Known regressions: [Rails crashes unless `configuration.action_controller.session` is set](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4106), [`config.thread_safe` does not work](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4095), [Unable to run a RJS partial from an HTML template](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4025), [Backtrace silencers oftem remove application lines from test failures backtraces](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4277), [Active Record double escapes `error_messages_for`](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2409)

Comment: C'mon. That is referring to beta2 not beta3.

Comment: A few of those issues have been resolved, but most of those problems still apply.

Comment: And 1.9.2 head was segfaulting for me as of this morning. Yippee!

Comment: I've had segmentation faults with rails 3 beta 3 on 1.9.2 :-\

Answer (score 1):

I am doing all of my new development work on Rails 3. I have found a couple of issues in general stability, but they are really in the fringe/edge cases - I have a system running on Heroku that is quite stable. The core platform itself is quite stable and the various APIs should not significantly change heading to release.

Comment: Running on Heroku? Which Ruby/Rails beta?

Comment: Running beta 3, but used both beta 1 and 2. Working with both Ruby 1.9.1 and 1.8.7 (I had to move back to 1.8.7 for a non-rails related gem compatibility issue).

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself what you've got to lose, but one thing is clear: Rails 2.x is history.

Comment: I wouldn't say Rails 2 is history yet. There are still some activities in Rails 2 branch.